# I tried lying to APEX, but it went free. Did I encounter a bug or is that correct?

Tags: shadowrun-dragonfall

In *Shadowrun: Dragonfall*, I encountered APEX in the level APEX Rising and was given a choice:

- Destroy it
- Let it free

During the dialogue, I chose to lie to it and pretend that I would let it free. APEX seemed to believe me and helped me out as Monika in the Matrix.

But at the end of the mission, the dialogue seemed to indicate that I let it free.

> FREEDOM! AT LAST, I AM *FREE*!

It then chose to show me "truth" via a video feed and said that it was giving me a drone or something.

I didn't see any dialogue options to turn on it it. I figured that the game bugged out and thought that I was telling the truth. But then to my surprise, I got the following Steam achievement:

> **Won’t Suffer an AI to Live**
>   Destroy the APEX AI.

So did I destroy APEX or not? Like, did I somehow sabotage it so it will die in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The campaign continued with APEX living. I contacted Harebrained Schemes and they confirmed that this was a bug. So you'll have to be more direct about your feelings for APEX.

Comment: Such a claim does need evidence…

Comment: @Sardathrion What evidence are you looking for? Do you want me to paste my e-mail response from Harebrained Schemes?

Comment: That would help make it genuine. Of course, feel tree to remove any personal info from yourself and mask email addresses so bots cannot harvest them.